# Is it possible to export raster data from PostGIS or MapServer as a base64 string?

Tags: postgis, mapserver, png, browser

Is it possible to output a PNG in a base64 string so that can be directly loaded into a browser? I've read through the PostGIS [documentation](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/RT_FAQ.html#id828626) which refer to the GDAL output formats. The GDAL output formats [here](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html) state the following:

> GDAL includes support for reading, and creating .png files. Greyscale,
>   pseudo-colored, Paletted, RGB and RGBA PNG files are supported as well
>   as precisions of eight and sixteen bits per sample.

Regarding MapServer, the only reference I can find is an [unanswered](http://osdir.com/ml/mapserver-users-gis/2006-01/msg00766.html) question asked on the mailing list six years ago.

I am wondering if I can generate a png text string in the following form so that it can be loaded into a browser using the [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) scheme:

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/x-png;base64,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" />
```

I would like to test this approach, as I am interested in the approach that MySociety used when creating [Mapumental](http://mapumental.com/). In the [description](http://www.mysociety.org/2012/11/08/mapumentals-secret-sauce-a-map-overlay-rendering-technology-you-might-find-interesting/) of how they made this tool, they refer to color-cycling of a base64 PNG string. The approach used by Mapumental is very complex - I am just interested in exploring how to even start this approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't you try something like...

```
SELECT encode(ST_AsPNG(rast), 'base64') FROM foo
```

Granted, I have no idea if that'll work but it is worth a shot.

Comment: Yes! That worked. I used `SELECT encode(ST_AsPNG(ST_AsRaster(ST_Buffer(ST_Point(1,5),10),150, 150, '2BUI')), 'base64')` and was able to load that into my browser.